# How to encode the Metal 3 argument buffer gpuAddress using only Swift

Tags: swift, metal

All of [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/buffers/managing_groups_of_resources_with_argument_buffers?language=objc) and sample projects for argument buffers are in Objective-C so perhaps they do not expect anyone to use Swift with the new Metal 3 argument buffer syntax.

The problem is the handy new `gpuAddress` property, used in Apple's example:

```
FragmentShaderArguments *argumentStructure = (FragmentShaderArguments *)_fragmentShaderArgumentBuffer.contents;


argumentStructure->exampleTexture = _texture.gpuResourceID;
argumentStructure->exampleBuffer = (float*) _indirectBuffer.gpuAddress;
argumentStructure->exampleSampler = _sampler.gpuResourceID;
argumentStructure->exampleConstant = bufferElements;
```

`gpuAddress` is a `UInt64`. Note how easily they have cast it as a `(float *)` so that it can be set on a struct field that is `float*`. This is not so easy in Swift it seems. The best I've come up with is this ugly bit:

```
#ifdef __METAL_VERSION__
#define BUFFER constant CustomStruct*
#else
#define BUFFER uint64_t
#endif

typedef struct {
    BUFFER structs;
} TestArgBuffer;
```

This allows me to use Swift to set that address using the `gpuAddress` on a shared struct definition.

Is this the expected way? I can't imagine it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the following implementation:

```
struct FragmentShaderArguments {
    var exampleTexture: MTLResourceID
    var exampleSampler: MTLResourceID
    var exampleBuffer: UnsafeRawPointer
    var exampleConstant: UInt32
}

let argumentStructure = fragmentShaderArgumentBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to: FragmentShaderArguments.self, capacity: 1)
argumentStructure.pointee.exampleTexture = texture.gpuResourceID
argumentStructure.pointee.exampleBuffer = UnsafeRawPointer(bitPattern: UInt(indirectBuffer.gpuAddress))!
argumentStructure.pointee.exampleSampler = sampler.gpuResourceID
argumentStructure.pointee.exampleConstant = UInt32(bufferElements)
```

Comment: The idea is to share the argument buffer data type in a shared header with Swift and Metal, but the casting of the gpu address appears to make this challenging in Swift, though it's easy in C.